# Forcing Ada to use minimum spec size for enumerated types with gnat 4.4

Tags: size, ada, gnat

I have an enumerated type that needs to be 4 bits but when I declare a variable of that type the compiler assigns that variable 8 bits.

Below is a simplified version of the code.

```
subtype ab_range_index is word range 0..3;
type ab_buffer_type is array(ab_range_index) of bit;

type Buffer is record
   ...
   var1        : some_buffer_type;
   Orig_AB_var : ab_buffer_type; 
   ...
end record;
for Buffer use record
  ...
  var1         at 16 range 0..5;
  Orig_AB_var  at 16 range 6..9;
  ...
end record;
...
type AB_type is (A,B);
for AB_type use (A => 0, B => 5);
for AB_type'Size use 4;
...
procedure Proc(AB_buff : ab_buffer_type) is 
AB_var : AB_type;                      -- AB_var'Size returns 8 in debugger.
for AB_var use at AB_buff'Address;
begin
   data_valid = AB_var'valid;          -- returns false since the variable 
                                       -- contains extra bits
   ...
```

This all worked under previous gnat versions but not under gnat 4.4.6. I understand that gnat is in compliance with the Ada spec.

Is there a way to force the compiler to make the AB_var in the above example to be 4 bits?
I've tried 'Object_Size but it needs to be a multiple of 8 bits.

Comment: Have you tried to set 'Size for the object (AB_var) and not just for the type?

Comment: I get the following compile error: "size for primitive object must be a power of 2 in the range 8-64" Thanks for the thought.

Comment: @user1998752: Which makes sense, as only a whole number of architecturally addressable bytes/bits can be allocated, i.e. 1/8, 2/16, 4/32, or 8/64

Comment: Are you using weird (unusual) compiler optimization options? I stick with `-O2`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any modern computer hardware that can allocate just 4 bits for a variable. The minimum would be an 8-bit byte.

And no offense, but I'm skeptical that any previous version of GNAT would have been able to do it either.

Now within a record that has an associated rep spec or suitable convention pragma, an individual field of type AB_Type could be allocated just 4 bits.

But not as a discrete variable.

Comment: I know I can compile the same code on gnat 4.1.2 and get the desired results. I'll have to check if the difference is indeed the size of the AB_var or something else. Your record idea might be usable as well. Thanks!

Comment: Marc - you are correct the AB_var was 8 bit under previous gnat versions. However, when the variable was assigned with the "for AB_var use at AB_buff'Address;" statement only the required 4 bits were used or evaluated. Any idea as to what's going on there, why it changed with new gnat version or how to get it to work as before?

Comment: I don't know what might have changed (and I've never done anything like this before). Some things I'd try: 1) Ensure that the address clause is referencing the start of the array, i.e. for AB_var use at AB_buff(AB_buff'First)'Address;    2) Try a pragma Convention(C, AB_Var), reason being to tell the compiler to leave that variable alone.

Comment: The pragma Convention does not seem to have any effect. I tried the Unchecked_Conversion route and that does work. Not sure it's the best solution though so would appreciate other ideas. Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Pragma Pack(` **`[type_name]`** `);` to the types, especially to the record. I recently had a case where even a record-specification clause would not work unless `pack` was attached to the type. (The aspect form can be used as well.)

Comment: That's not going to get him a 4-bit variable.

Comment: Pragme pack is for arrays or records only. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I had to apply it to the record in order for the rep-clause to be accepted. Odd thing, that.

Answer (score 1):

There's almost always something to be said for posting a compilable reproducer. I'm not sure what your code is really like, but this works just fine with GCC 4.8.0:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Small_Parameter_Conversion is
   type M_N_Type is (M, N);
   for M_N_Type use (M => 0, N => 5);
   for M_N_Type'Size use 4;
   type Fill is array (Positive range <>) of Boolean;
   for Fill'Component_Size use 1;
   type Import is record
      M_N : M_N_Type;
      Filler : Fill (1 .. 4);
   end record;
   for Import use record
      M_N at 0 range 0 .. 3;
      Filler at 0 range 4 .. 7;
   end record;
   type A_B_Type is (A, B);
   for A_B_Type use (A => 0, B => 5);
   for A_B_Type'Size use 4;
   procedure Proc (Input : M_N_Type) is
      A_B : A_B_Type;
      for A_B'Address use Input'Address;
   begin
      if not A_B'Valid then
         Put_Line ("invalid.");
      else
         Put_Line (A_B'Img);
      end if;
   end Proc;
   V : Import;
begin
   V := (M_N => M, Filler => (others => True));
   Proc (V.M_N);
   V := (M_N => N, Filler => (others => True));
   Proc (V.M_N);
end Small_Parameter_Conversion;
```

That said, `Unchecked_Conversion` is the better way to go. The last paragraph but two of the [GNAT Reference Manual section on Address Clauses](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Address-Clauses.html) points out that using overlays is implementation-dependent (though I couldn't find where it says this in the RM).

One possible route to error would be if `M_N_Type` was in fact defined as

```
type M_N_Type is (M, N, O);
for M_N_Type use (M => 0, N => 5, O => 6);
```

and `Proc` is called as

```
V := (M_N => O, Filler => (others => True));
Proc (V.M_N);
```

Then, sure enough, it prints `invalid.`.

Comment: I tried the sample code above, and sure enough it worked. The data is populated from a file which may be the cause of the issue as in your second example. I tried to duplicate the error in a small compilable program but don't think it's a good use effort. Thanks for the help!